# Access shared folders on Windows Server 2019 from Windows Home machines

Tags: domain, network-share, windows-server-2019

A small company moved from the old Windows-Homer-Server to Windows-Server 2019. Office computers running a Home-Version of windows (=not able to join a domain) need to access shares on the server.

I read about activating the Guest-Account on the server, but **I need to restrict** the access on the server's shared folders **to specific machines**/users. In the WHS you were able to give permissions to specific users on specific machines "\machine1\userA" but with Windows Server 2019 it does not work. (won't find the machines)

How can computers (that are not in the domain) access the shared folders on a DC using authentication? What permissions need to be applied to the shared folders?

Isn't it possible to simply add a domain-user on the server and access the share-folders with that user through the windows-home computers? Can a computer outside of the domain authenticate with a domain user?

Comment: `Isn't it possible to simply add a domain-user on the server and access the share-folders with that user through the windows-home computers`? Should be. Also if they have the same username/password on their workstation it should use pass through authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it possible to simply add a domain-user on the server and access
>   the share-folders with that user through the windows-home computers?
>   Can a computer outside of the domain authenticate with a domain user?

You can create user accounts on the server for each of your users. Secure the shared folders on the server appropriately for these users. Then from the client computers map a network drive to the appropriate server shares and provide the credentials for one of the user accounts you created on the server.

[image]